# Migrate X-cart 4.1.8 to X-cart 5 business

Tags: upgrade, x-cart

I have to upgrade my X-cart version. Current version is 4.1.8 and have to upgrade to X-cart 5 business.

Can I directly migrate to 5 or have to upgrade first to latest version of X-cart 4?

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 6):

You can definitely upgrade directly to X-Cart 5.
For that just use the Migration Wizard module: https://market.x-cart.com/addons/migration-wizard.html

One note though, this module does not transfer custom data and custom modifications of functionality and design. It only transfers data from X-Cart 4 to X-Cart 5.

If you need to transfer custom changes, they will have to be re-implemented.

Comment: I am getting error in upgrade pack 4.1.8 to 4.1.12. Doc says If some files have the result status 'Could not patch' it means that the patch cannot be applied to these files automatically because they were significantly modified, the patch for these files should be applied manually. You can ignore it by deselecting the checkbox at the bottom of page on the first step "Tick here if you want to try to apply the patch to these files". But i can't see this options

Comment: You do not need to upgrade your X-Cart 4.1.8 to 4.1.12 in order to use the Migration Wizard module.

If you still want to upgrade to 4.1.12 for any reason, then this problem needs an investigation. You can try to debug it yourself, ask for the help on X-Cart forums or contact X-Cart's support team.

Answer (score 1):

X-cart 4 and X-cart 5 are completely different carts with completely different database structures. You can do the *conversion*, but that's *not* an "upgrade" but rather re-building a new store.

You might consider instead just updating to the latest version of "X-cart Classic", which is 4.7.10... and has a database structure and template structure that's going to be MUCH easier to adapt to.

If you do that, then per the [X-cart wiki](https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Upgrading) you'd want to take your store from 4.1.8 -> 4.1.12 -> 4.5.0 -> 4.7.10 (latest).

Comment: I am using X-cart gold. In my account I have available upgrade pack from 4.1.8 to 4.1.12. So what i have to do after 4.1.12? Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Upgrade pack and Database upgrade script both are different?

Comment: I am getting error in upgrade pack 4.1.8 to 4.1.12. Doc says If some files have the result status 'Could not patch' it means that the patch cannot be applied to these files automatically because they were significantly modified, the patch for these files should be applied manually. You can ignore it by deselecting the checkbox at the bottom of page on the first step "Tick here if you want to try to apply the patch to these files".

But i can't see this options